# Has Facebook Graph Search been recently entirely removed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

FB graph search used to work via direct links until today.

See example link:
https://www.facebook.com/search/str/anything/stories-keyword/intersect/stories-live

It returns

> We couldn't find anything for **anything**

And the same message for any search.

Any ideas what's happened? Do you see the same page when open this link?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: @CBroe, I will delete it if you advice which board is better for this question

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason.

It's like a ban at facebook. When using another account and different IP everything works again.